# How to insert an array of bytes into a blob cell in a database?

Tags: c#, sql, odbc

I use this code to edit data in the database. When data like int or string everything works, but I can’t understand how can I insert an array of bytes into a cell with a BLOB data type.
3 days already by storm Google, youtube, but I can not find a solution.

```
OdbcTransaction transaction = null;
                OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand();

                transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

                command.Connection = connection;
                command.Transaction = transaction;
                
                
                command.CommandText = "UPDATE tb_vs SET te_file=" + bytes + " WHERE te_comp LIKE '" + ParStr + "'";
                //command = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE tb_vs SET te_file=" + bytes + " WHERE te_comp LIKE '" + ParStr + "'", connection);
                //command.Parameters.Add("@byte", OdbcType.Blob).Value = bytes;
                

                command.ExecuteReader();
                transaction.Commit();
```

Comment: Learn to use parameterized queries.

Comment: For some reason, this does not work with my database. Only through OdbcTransaction.

Answer (score 0):

This code prompted me

```
using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
using (var command = new OdbcCommand())

command.Connection = connection;
command.Transaction = transaction;

command.CommandText =
    "UPDATE tb_vs SET te_file = ? WHERE te_comp LIKE ?";

command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OdbcType.Binary).Value = bytes;
command.Parameters.Add("@p2", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = ParStr;

int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
transaction.Commit();
```

but it gives a new error:

System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: "ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft] [ODBC TransBase Driver] [TransBase] General error.
TransBase Exec error report:
type of parameter 0 does not match (got binchar (*), wanted blob)

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the array to a string. Because Oracle does not recognize C# arrays

Comment: When sending data to a database, both parties, the source and the destination, must know the type of data. The database does not know the data in the array. Or rather, he doesn't know the array. For this reason, you must first convert the data inside the array to a string and then save it as a string in the database. Otherwise, you must store each in-array information separately in different database cells

Comment: any other explanations rather than, "You need to convert the array to a string".

Comment: I need to convert the array to blob type, not string.
In string I can, but how in blob?

Comment: In database cells, only one data is stored. While the array itself contains a number of cells containing information. The blob data string is only one piece of data in total. For example, a photo that has been converted to binary form. Long binary string containing photo information. I think you understand the concept of blob data. Now you need to use the loop to convert an array to a binary string.

Comment: Break the information inside the array into a single string. To identify the beginning and end of each data cell in the array, you must define a specific binary sign and place a loop between the converted cells in each iteration. This way you will have a long binary string that can be stored inside a database cell. But you have to convert it to an array again when called.
The best way, in my opinion, is to store the information in the array one by one in separate cells of the database